# Head miscellaneous script is not being added

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

I'm adding a tracking script to "Miscellaneous Scripts" at Design->HTML Head section but it is not working. If a search for the script added in my shop html source code it does not appear.

Please find the next screenshot:
https://cdnweb5.vikinguard.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/3.png

---

Adding the script to "Miscellaneous HTML" at Footer section works properly. Any idea of why it works from footer and does not work from head?

Comment: change the scope from the top left select and make sure that on the website or store view level you have the "Use default value" checkbox checked

Comment: @Marius could you please put your comment as answer :)

Comment: @RajeevKTomy. Yes boss. I did it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments....
change the scope from the top left select and make sure that on the website or store view level you have the "Use default value" checkbox checked

Answer (score 0):

Also don't forget to clear your Magento cache: **System** > **Cache Management** > **Flush Magento Cache**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the following code has not been removed from the file:

`/app/design/frontend/{PACKAGE}/{THEME}/template/page/html/head.phtml`

As follows:

```
<?php echo $this->getIncludes() ?>
```

This is Magento’s hook to include this content in your theme’s `<head>`. (It’s there in the `base` package, but if your theme has overridden this file and you’ve left this out, that could be your problem.)

Then, of course, clear all caches and ensure your code is in the “Miscellaneous HTML” text field for your store’s store view.